# jqgrid inline edit row validation

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a Jqgrid with multiple row inline edit. I need to add edit rule for the grid.

I have two columns namely Requested Qty(value is already present) and Approved Qty (which I need to enter in Edit mode). In edit mode, entered value of approved qty should be less than/equal to Requested qty.

How can I get value of other column in edit rule ? How can I perform row validation to compare other column values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `save row` click function, you can validate one cell's value compared to another:

```
$("#yourSaveButtonID").click(function (event) {
    // get the current row's ID
    var rowID = $("#yourGridID").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');

    // get the Approved Qty value
    var cell_approvedQty = $("#yourGridID #" + rowID + "_approved_qty_column_name").val();

    // get the Requested Qty value
    var cell_requestedQty = $("#yourGridID #" + rowID + "_requested_qty_column_name").val();

    // compare them
    if (cell_approvedQty > cell_requestedQty) {
        alert("Approved Qty must be less than or equal to Requested Qty");
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

You will have to change `_approved_qty_column_name` and `_requested_qty_column_name` to your actual column names. Just remember to keep the leading `_` - it is required for this selector.

Comment: getCell returns HTML content , not the value. Please help

Comment: @kalyanasundaramv I just updated my answer. I changed the way we get the value of those cells since they are `input` elements, with text inside.